# GIF as icon for my Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and I'm trying to create a simple Media Player application. I was wondering, however, if it is possible to use an animated GIF file for the Icon that displays in the top left corner of the application itself, as pointed out in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4QOo.jpg). The language I am using is C#. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and, if so, how I would go about achieving this?

`EDIT:`  Okay, there seems to be some confusion about what I'm asking, so perhaps I should provide some further details...The application I am designing is just a simple media player that is designed to play .wav files assigned to specific buttons. The application isn't a browser, or anything like that. The picture I provided was actually cropped down from this picture [here]. I apologize, as I am new to programming, and everything I have learned up to this point, I learned through the Great And Powerful YOUTUBE. ^.^
If you guys need any further information, let me know, and I'll provide what I can! Thanks again!!!

`EDIT 2:` Oops, I did the wrong image! I'm sorry! [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBV67.jpg) is the correct image. My apologies!

`EDIT 3:` Wow, that's where I got confusing...the site changed the title of my post automatically and I didn't catch it. So sorry, all...

Comment: Not using regular windows chrome. You'd have to create your own window chrome.

Comment: Did you mean `Winforms`? The picture is a window, not a web page.

Comment: You don't explain what you are doing this in. If it's WPF, then you'd have to set [Window.WindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) to none, which removes all the standard window chrome and then you'd have to recreate it's functionality (close box, min/max box, icon, resizing) yourself

Comment: Are you able to load in a animated gif instead of an `.ico`? > You have the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, NO.

But you can create a sequence of icons that represent your animation and change them periodically to giv the user the sensation of animation. I just cant attest that it will be smooth enougth.

Comment: thank you, @PauloJunior for your help. I appreciate it. And to everyone else, thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be supported widely not in many browsers see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support)
. Seems you would need to create an animated gif using some external photo editor. I believe the required dimensions are 16X16 and reference it with something like

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/image.gif" />
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, Jim...I'm so sorry, I really don't know the difference. What little knowledge I have of programming comes from 3 semesters of computer science I took in Community College six years ago...I apologize to all for being such a newbie...I understand if you find me frustrating, but I really want to learn this...If you could help me, you'd make my day. Thank you guys for your time.